# Bash: Append character(s) after echo $variable in a for loop

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, echo, substitution

I'm trying to parse a csv file and get certain values from fields, which works:

```
$ for line in $(cat test.csv); do regiovalue="$(echo $line | awk -F';' '{print $4}')"; echo "regio: ${regiovalue}"; done
regio: TOG
regio: APP
regio: APP
regio: APP
```

But I need to append another character at the end of the echo output:

```
$ for line in $(cat test.csv); do regiovalue="$(echo $line | awk -F';' '{print $4}')"; echo "regio: ${regiovalue};"; done
;egio: TOG
;egio: APP
;egio: APP
;egio: APP
```

As you can see the added semicolon character was added at the begin of the line and replaced the first character (r) of the line. It doesn't matter if it's a semicolon or any other character by the way.

This only happens in a loop (both for and while read tested), a straightforward echo works without problem:

```
$ regiovalue=TOG; echo "regio: ${regiovalue};"
regio: TOG;
```

Bash version:

```
$ bash --version | grep bash
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

1. Why does this happen? I checked the documentation but couldn't find anything particular about a character substitution in a loop.
2. How do I get the output (variable value and additional characters) in a single echo?

Comment: Why not use `awk` to process the csv file and skip the Bash loop altogether? Way faster and easier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that your lines probably end with `\r`... This causes the cursor to return to the beginning of the line (*carriage return*).

```sh
$ printf "hello\r\nhow\r\nare\r\nyou\r\n" \
>     | hexdump -Cv
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 0d 0a 68  6f 77 0d 0a 61 72 65 0d  |hello..how..are.|
00000010  0a 79 6f 75 0d 0a                                 |.you..|
00000016
```

You should filter this out, possibly using `tr`:

```sh
$ printf "hello\r\nhow\r\nare\r\nyou\r\n" \
>     | tr -d $'\r' \
>     | hexdump -Cv
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 0a 68 6f  77 0a 61 72 65 0a 79 6f  |hello.how.are.yo|
00000010  75 0a                                             |u.|
00000012
```

Or setting `awk`'s Record Separator:

```sh
$ printf "hello\r\nhow\r\nare\r\nyou\r\n" \
>     | awk -vRS='\r\n' '{print $0}' \
>     | hexdump -Cv
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 0a 68 6f  77 0a 61 72 65 0a 79 6f  |hello.how.are.yo|
00000010  75 0a                                             |u.|
00000012
```

---

As pointed out by dawg, you could just use `awk` to do everything:

```sh
awk -vRS='\r\n' -F';' '{print "regio: " $4}' < test.csv
```

Comment: Holy sh!t. I didn't think of that but it's exactly the reason. Turns out the csv file I received from someone in the Windows world does indeed have carriage returns at the end. I manually created another csv file and here it ran through just fine. 
So I appended the tr command to the loop and indeed it works:
`$ for line in $(cat test.csv); do regiovalue="$(echo $line | awk -F';' '{print $4}' | tr -d $'\r')"; echo "regio: ${regiovalue};"; done `

Comment: It would be best to filter the `\r` upfront: change `for line in $(cat test.csv); do` to `for line in $(cat test.csv | tr -d $'\r'); do`

Comment: Thx Attie, much appreciated!